# Optimised code to find no of pairs of indices (i,j) such that i<=j and (a[i] +a [j]) is a sum power of two

Tags: python

Tried using 2 for loops but getting time out issue.Array can have negative elements as well

```
def pairSummingToPowerOfTwo(a):
    
    if len(a)==1 and (a[0] and (not(a[0] & (a[0] - 1))) ):
        return 1
    
    count  = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i, len(a)):

            sum = a[i] + a[j]
            if (sum and (not(sum & (sum - 1)))):
                count += 1
                        
    return count
```

Please suggest optimized approach

Comment: What is the length of input? What is the value range of input?

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the nested loop to iterate the values directly as a single loop with

```
for x, y in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(a, 2):
    sum = x + y
    # Rest of code unchanged
```

That handles the `i <= j` condition without ever actually producing `i` or `j`, you just get the associated values directly; unnecessary repeated indexing is a surprisingly expensive task. There are other things you could do to reduce the number of lines of code (stacking `filter(None` and `itertools.starmap(operator.add` to move filtering for non-zero and the summing to the C layer) but they're unlikely to improve performance markedly (the bytecode for these operations isn't that inefficient).